# Black does not support "Format Selection" command

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, python-black

I need to indent my python file in VS Code. I followed the normal procedure:

> ```
> On Windows Shift + Alt + F
> On Mac Shift + Option + F
> On Linux Ctrl + Shift + I
> ```

But my question is every time when I try to format python file it it says

> Black does not support "Format Selection"

So someone can explain what's going wrong here?

My python version is `Python 3.7.6`.
VS Code details:

```
Version: 1.46.0 (user setup)
Commit: a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321
Date: 2020-06-10T09:03:20.462Z
Electron: 7.3.1
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

Comment: you can try autopep8. it supports format selection

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It sounds like your keybindings are set to run "Format Selection" instead of "Format Document"; Black only supports the latter, not the former. If you run the "Format Document" command that should work without issue.

Comment: what formatter you suggest if I need to have "format selection" ?

Comment: We have not added explicit support to any formatter for selection formatting, so I don't have a recommendation.

Comment: `autopep8` does support `Format Selection`, as opposed to `black`. That's the only reason I use `autopep8`, I'd prefer `black` for the rest.

Answer (score 72):

In my situation (select `black` as the Python Formatting Provider in VS Code Settings), I encountered this warning **everytime when I pasting some text into the editor**.

And the official documentation of VS Code [has a solution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting) specifically for it:

> When using the black formatter, VS Code issues the following warning when pasting source code into the editor: **Black does not support the "Format Select" command.**
>
> To prevent this warning, add the following entry to your **user or workspace settings** to disable format on paste for Python files:

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnPaste": false
}
```

Comment: As per the official documentation you must also have `"[python]": { "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file" }`

Comment: This response fixed my problem!

Answer (score 16):

Make sure to **Editor: Format On Save Mode > File** [image]

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! that worked for me! for me it was sat on the user setting to be modifications

Comment: Bingo! Clearly does the job. In most dev shops CI/CD will require all files to be `black`d anyway so it doesn't hurt in most cases that you're formatting the whole file. Nice.

Comment: Also set `Format On Paste` to `False`, because Black can't format paste chunks.

Answer (score 5):

Black does not support the format selection option by design. In this bug you can [find the reasoning](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/134).

If you want to use black you must configure to format all file and disable the format selection. Your settings.json must have this configuration:

```
 "[python]": { 
     "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",       
     "editor.formatOnPaste": false
 }
```

If you really want to use Black in an existing project, my suggestion is to try to use [darker](https://github.com/akaihola/darker). I've been successfully using it in a code that I started to develop using black, but a coworker didn't use. Now I can edit it without breaking `git blame` info.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an old setting

```json
"[python]": {
  "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications"
}
```

To fix the issue I've replaced it to be this:

```json
"[python]": {
  "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file"
}
```

And problem disappear.